# Running debug on two separate devices in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I have 2 Android devices connected to my computer.
I need to debug them both at the same time since I am sending data back and forth between them.
When I set them both to debug mode it will only stop one at a time.
I can't stop the "sender" immeditaly after the send and then debug the "receiver". It just doesn't like it!

I really need to be able to run two completely sessions.
I tried opening a new Eclipse window but it doesn't help.
Any stops I put apply to both and if any device is in debug mode then it applies to both instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using two machines. as the debug port both of them are trying to connect to is the same for a single instance of eclipse.

Comment: Not really an option as I would have to find another computer and then install Eclipse etc. Would also mean copying over any source changes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think that it's possible to debug multiple devices on the same computer using Eclipse, at least for now.