# How to debug and test android networking app

Tags: android, network-programming

I have an app with 3 different user profiles, each of them are communicating through XMPP. There are debugging information in each profile. I would like to debug all in the same time over real network communication.
Is there a way to have 3 instances of ADB for debugging the same application but from 3 different emulators/devices within the same PC?
or what would be the best practice for doing so?

Answer (score 0):

try [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49416/how-do-i-debug-two-android-devices-simultaneously-in-eclipse) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060648/running-debug-on-two-separate-devices-in-eclipse) links as well. For **Same App Multiple device Debugging**. I Guess the First Link will help you more. Hope It Helps.